# Opera loads nothing - MyBB forum website

Tags: opera, forum

I've got a website (www.ferfereh.ir - sorry it's not english) and I've installed a MyBB forum for it with this sub-domain (www.forum.ferfereh.ir). The strange thing is it doesn't work on the Opera browser, nothing gets loaded and the page is all white. I've tested it on other browsers, everything is fine. Does anyone have any idea why this might happen. I even tested my friend's MyBB forum and the same thing happens for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is what you get - the server sends Opera a completely empty file, Content-length 0. I can only assume it is some kind of bug in MyBB..

I also tested in Chrome, and it gets no content either.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: It was the new Beta SEO plugin I had installed. I deactivated the plugin and now it works on all browsers.